# NGINX Reverse Proxy + ngx_upstream_resolveMK - Trying to resolve SRV from ECS Service Discovery Route53 Auto Naming

Tags: nginx, networking, amazon-route53, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I'm currently having an issue with ECS Service Discovery and Route53 Auto Naming.

I have added the Service Registry to the service and all the Hosted Zones records are being populated automatically.
But I cannot seem to work out how to resolve the DNS SRV records with NGINX + [ngx_upstream_resolveMK](https://github.com/HatsuneMiku3939/ngx_upstream_resolveMK).

```
# DNS RESOLVER
resolver ns-x.awsdns-xx.com valid=10s;

# UPSTREAMS
upstream kibana {
  resolveMK servicediscovery.ecs service=kibana;
}

# HOST - kibana.example.com
server {
  server_name kibana.example.com;
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://kibana/;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  }
}
```

ERROR: `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "servicediscovery.ecs" in /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/kibana.conf:3`

So it appears that there is a missing A record needed to resolve "servicediscovery.ecs" to the Route 53 Private Zone.

Do I need to manually add this? or is there a way to dynamically add this A record?

I think this is the cause of the problem, but I'm still learning and might be way off.

**UPDATE:**

I read you can also use xxx.xxx.xxx.2 to access the DNS via AWS VPC
I have tested using a new resolver without much luck.

```
# DNS RESOLVER
resolver xxx.xxx.0.2 valid=10s;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx has a problem using internal DNS when you want use it in ECS.

I was successful after using HA-Proxy.

It uses the "links" option of Docker, and HA-Proxy support uses `/etc/hosts` file.

1. First, use "links" option of Docker and setting "environment variables" (eg. `LINK_APP`, `LINK_PORT`).
2. Second, fill these "environment variables" into `haproxy.cfg`.

Also, I recommend you use "dynamic port mapping" to ALB. it makes more flexible works.

**taskdef.json:**

```
{
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<APP_NAME>_ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "<APP_NAME>-rp",
        "image": "gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "memoryReservation": <MEMORY_RESV>,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 0,
            "containerPort": 80,
            "protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          "<APP_NAME>"
        ],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "LINK_PORT",
            "value": "<SERVICE_PORT>"
          },
          {
            "name": "LINK_APP",
            "value": "<APP_NAME>"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "<APP_NAME>",
        "image": "<IMAGE_NAME>",
        "essential": true,
        "memoryReservation": <MEMORY_RESV>,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": <SERVICE_PORT>
          }
        ],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "PORT",
            "value": "<SERVICE_PORT>"
          },
          {
            "name": "APP_NAME",
            "value": "<APP_NAME>"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
      "EC2"
    ],
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "family": "<APP_NAME>"
  }
```

**haproxy.cfg:**

```
global
    daemon
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend http
    bind *:80

    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]

    compression algo gzip
    compression type text/css text/javascript text/plain application/json application/xml

    default_backend app

backend app
    server static "${LINK_APP}":"${LINK_PORT}"
```

> See :
>
> Github : https://github.com/gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy
>
> Docker image : gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy:latest

Here is more detail [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58390515/12200437)!

Comment: Awesome response on this. I have changed the accepted answer to be yours with your detailed solution.

Comment: Glad could be of help you !

Answer (score 1):

We resolved this issue by swapping to [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

Another issue was to use the correct format for the Service Dsicovery.

Create a new private namespace with the name `_ip.xxxxxxx.ecs` and name the service discovery name `_prometheus`. Both can be achieved when you create a new service in `ecs`.