# Nginx not resolving DNS - AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 services in AWS ECS in a VPC. We'll call them Service A and Service B. Service A has an nginx container and I am trying to `proxy_pass` to service B. I am using service connect for DNS between the services.

I have been looking at [Nginx internal dns resolve issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145595/nginx-internal-dns-resolve-issue) but I am still have the issue. I have full exec access into the service A container as well for troubleshooting. Below is my config

I have a VPC with DNS enabled

[image]

Then I have my `nginx.conf` which is abbreviated:

```
http {

    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    resolver 169.254.169.253;
    # I have also tried using the CIDR of VPC + 2 in my case
    # 10.0.0.2
    #I have also set the variable as shown in the SO question above
    #But that cause other errors 

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://service-B:8080;

    }

}
```

When I run this all and make a request I see in the nginx logs that `service-B` gets resolved to `127.255.0.1`. And it always gets resolved to this and then I get a timeout.

When I `exec` into Service A, I can telnet to service B and it connects. But when I curl I get an error of `upstream request timeout`

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Check IP address 169.254.169.253
Then VPN DNS in check resolver in nginx.

proxy_set_header Host $host;
(error_log /path/to/error.log error;')
No firewall rules
Port between service B and nginx

Answer (score 0):

When using Service Connect, communication between NGINX (Service A) and Service B can be achieved even *without* needing resolver.

In Service Connect configuration,

- select the same Namespace (let's say 'DevCluster') &
- run NGINX (Service A) in "Client side only" mode &
- run Service B in "Client and server" mode

Then, use the below config in nginx

```
http {
    upstream backendServiceB {
        server service-B.devcluster:8080;   # <-- service connect endpoint
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backendServiceB;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The service connect endpoints that are created for an ECS service are visible in the **Configuration and networking** tab -> **Service Connect** section of the service in the ECS management console.

In the minimal client - server service config (i.e. when custom Discovery or DNS names are *not* provided), service connect endpoint would be `<<port_name_in_task_def>>.<<cluster_name>>:<<port>>`.

Answer (score -1):

I deduce that the issue may be caused by misconfigured DNS settings. Verify whether the `/etc/resolv.conf` file records the DNS server addresses you need.

The content of `/etc/resolv.conf` appears like:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.8.1
nameserver fe80::801c:8ff:fe03:b3c0%enp6s0
nameserver 172.18.8.254
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 172.21.0.21
nameserver 172.21.201.22
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver fe80::e006:4bff:fe85:5a73%enxe2064b855a74
```

Each line in the file configures a DNS server address, and the system will request DNS record from top to bottom. If you need to modify this file, it is recommended to use the `nmtui` tool to configure the correct DNS server addresses for the network card.